# Order of operations in 2 and 3 phase atomic commit protocols

Tags: dc.distributed-comp

I am currently reading through this http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/philbe/chapter7.pdf chapter about distributed recovery. The chapter focuses on 2 phase atomic commit (2PC) and 3 phase atomic commit (3PC). Two related questions have me stumped.

> **7.11**: In  the  2PC protocol  the  coordinatorfirst  decides Commit  (by  writing  a  commit  record  to  its  site’s DT  log)  and  then 
>   sends COMMIT  messages to  the  participants.  Suppose  the  order  of
>   these  two  steps is  reversed.  Show  that  this  variation  of  2PC 
>   is  non-blocking  if
>
> a.  there  are no  communication  failures  and  at most  one process 
>   can  fail,
>
> or
>
> b.  there  are no  communication  failures  and  processes have  the 
>   ability  to  broadcast  messages atomically  (i.e.,  so that  either 
>   all  recipients  get  it  or  no  recipient  does).
>
> How  does  this  variation  of  2PC  affect  the  recovery 
>   procedures?  Give  recovery  procedures  that  work  for  the 
>   modified  2PC  protocol.
>
> **7.22**: In  3PC,  does the  relative  order  of  sending  COMMIT  messages and  writ-  ing  a commit  record  in  the  DT  log  matter? 
>   What  about  the  relative  order  of  sending  ABORT  messages and 
>   writing  an  abort  record?

The first does not seem particularly hard, but I am unsure of how to actually prove that a program is non-blocking. The second question is a bit more complex. My intuition is that 3PC has enough built in safeguards with the PRE-COMMIT phase that changing the order wouldn't matter, but again I am uncertain of what a proof of this would look like.

Comment: could there be a way to build the 3PC proof out of the 2PC proof ie as a generalization or extension? 2PC is widespread and 3PC sounds rather unconventional. it might help to include short defns of 2PC and 3PC.

Comment: try this [can 3PC guarantee atomicity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746875/how-can-the-three-phase-commit-protocol-3pc-guarantee-atomicity) stackoverflow

Comment: This question is part of a homework assignment which the professor has explicitly requested to be an individual effort. The fact that it's being asked here not only violates the school's honor code but also is personally offensive to all other students that are abiding by the rules laid out by the professor. Please refrain from posting answers to this question until Monday, April 15th, 2013 at 3:15 EST.

Comment: @comp735student what school? and by the way "individual effort" does not necessarily preclude using the internet or violate an honor code. however its true that homework questions are discouraged on cstheory.se although this is probably acceptable on cs.se

Comment: @vzn: I thought it would be fairly obvious that asking someone on the internet the answer to the question precludes individual effort.

Comment: the point is that if the instructor wants some kind of specific policy wrt "using" the internet, (of which there are many "uses") they should probably state precisely what it is.